# Access HashMap key in Thymeleaf

Tags: java, spring, printing, hashmap, thymeleaf

I want to access any index of a HashMap to retrieve an `Id` through this code:

```
th:text="'Network Id: ' + ${poolHashrates[0].key.networkHashrate.id}"
```

`poolHashrates` is a `HashMap`,
`networkHashrate` is a separate variable in `key` variable

Basically, all the `networkHashrates` in `key` have the same `Id`, so I could actually access any element, no matter what the index is.

I've also tried:

```
th:text="'Network Id: ' + ${poolHashrates.get(key).networkHashrate.id}"
th:text="'Network Id: ' + ${poolHashrates['key'].networkHashrate.id}"
```

None of these works. I keep getting

```
Exception evaluating SpringEL expression: "poolHashrates['key'].networkHashrate.id"
```

or

```
SpelEvaluationException: EL1007E: Property or field 'networkHashrate' cannot be found on null
```

I was able to print the `Id` in Intellij console, so it apparently exsists.

Comment: Did you tried using Iterator, or keySet method to iterate over

Comment: Are those Thymeleaf methods? Can't find any info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you want to get an element out of the HashMap without knowing any of the keys?  I think that's kind of silly... but it is possible.  Here is one such way:

```
<span th:text="${poolHashrates.get(poolHashrates.keySet().toArray()[0])}" />
```

That will get you an element of the `poolHashrates` `HashMap`.  I'm still unclear why you keep talking about `key`, but never really define what you mean.  Is key really a property (with a `getKey()` and `setKey()`) on whatever you are storing in your `HashMap`?  If so, then your final expression would look like this:

```
<span th:text="${poolHashrates.get(poolHashrates.keySet().toArray()[0]).key.networkHashrate.id}" />
```

or maybe

```
<span th:text="${poolHashrates.get(poolHashrates.keySet().toArray()[0]).networkHashrate.id}" />
```

(Are you confusing `.key` with a variable you get when you iterate over a `HashMap` with `th:each` in Thymeleaf?)